# Static Variable Declaration (C)

Tags: c, declaration, language-lawyer, static-variables

Are the following two `static` variable declarations equivalent?

1.

```
    static int var1;
    static int var2;
    static int var3;
```

2.

```
    static int var1, var2, var3;
```

More specifically, in case 2, will all variables be `static`, or just `var1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the declarations in case `1` and `2` are identical. We can see this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.5` *Declarators* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> Each declarator declares one identifier, and asserts that when an
>   operand of the same form as the declarator appears in an expression,
>   it designates a function or object **with the scope, storage duration,
>   and type indicated by the declaration specifiers**.

We can see the grammar from section `6.7` *Declarations* is as follows:

```
declaration:
   declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
```

the *declaration-specifiers* include storage duration:

```
declaration-specifiers:
   storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
```

so the storage duration specifier applies to all the *declarators* in the *init-declarator-list* which has the following grammar:

```
init-declarator-list:
   init-declarator
   init-declarator-list , init-declarator
init-declarator:
   declarator
   declarator = initializer
```

You may wonder about pointers, they are handled handled differently and we can see this from the grammar in `6.7.5` for *declarators*:

```
declarator:
    pointeropt direct-declarator
[...]
pointer:
    * type-qualifier-listopt
    * type-qualifier-listopt pointer
```

Comment: More info: the difference between this  and `const int a, b, c;` is that `static` (along with `extern`, `typedef`, `auto` and `register`) is a *storage class specifier*, whereas `const` (and `volatile` and `restrict`) are *qualifiers* . The grammar rules are different for specifiers than for qualifiers.

Comment: "The grammar rules are different for specifiers than for qualifiers." so how about `static volatile int a, b, c;`.  Will `a`, `b` and `c` all end up the same?

Answer (score 7):

They're equivalent.

In case 2, all the variables will be static.

The storage class specifier `static` applies to all the declared variables in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You've just shown how variables can be declared differently.

```
 static int var1, var2, var3;
```

or

```
static int var1;
static int var2;
static int var3;
```

has the same meaning

ie; a variable of same data type(and also of same storage class) can be declared individually or all together once

Answer (score 1):

```
static int var1, var2, var3;
```

is equivalent to:

```
static int var1;
static int var2;
static int var3;
```

case 1 or case 2 both are used for readability purpose but meaning is same.